# Looping over the elements of a given list up to certain number using next() method

Tags: python, algorithm

I would like to obtain the number of distinct prime factors of a natural number n between 2 and N (for N a large number). For this, I thought first creating a list of prime numbers. Then, in order to obtain the list of distinct prime factors of n, check the prime numbers in my list, until the square root of n, that divide n. If a prime divides n then check for the next one in the list.

This is what I tried:

```
def prime_eratosthenes(n):
    not_primes = []
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i not in not_primes:
            #print (i)
            for j in range(i*i, n+1, i):
                not_primes.append(j)                
    return [item for item in range(2,n) if item not in  set(not_primes)]

n=100
L = prime_eratosthenes(n)

def num_primefactors(n):
  prime_div=[]

  x=L[0]
  while x*x<=n:
    if n%x==0:
      n=n//x
      prime_div.append(x)
    x=next(L)

  return len(prime_div) 

num_primefactors(14)
```

It gives me the error:
'' 'list' object is not an iterator ''

So I tried to use myit = iter(L), and substitute 'L' by 'myit' but then it gives me the error:
''  'list_iterator' object is not subscriptable  ''

How could I fix this code?

Comment: There is no `next()` for a list. Your method returns the entire list. Just use a `for` loop to iterate through the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x=L[0]
while x*x<=n:
    if n%x==0:
        n=n//x
        prime_div.append(x)
    x=next(L)
```

The issue is still the same as it was when you first posted your question: you're expecting `L` to be both a list of primes *and* an iterator over the list.  This is a contradiction in functionality.

The straightforward way is to use the known iterator, `for`, and simply exit the loop when you hit your limit:

```
for factor in L:
    if factor * factor > n:
        break
    if n % factor == 0:
        prime_div.append(factor)
        n //= factor
```

Note that `for ... in L` **constructs** an iterator over `L`.  There is no need to create and instrument your own.

Here is a reconstruction of your loop, doing the "manual" iteration:

```
prime_stream = iter(L)
factor = next(prime_stream)
while factor * factor <= n:
    if n % factor == 0:
        prime_div.append(factor)
        n //= factor
    factor = next(prime_stream, n+1)  # Ensures loop exit when we run out of primes

return len(prime_div)
```

Comment: Thanks ... bad terminology on my part.  "in L" provides the iterator.